# How to locate a mismatched text delimiter

Tags: regex, perl, sed

I'm trying to remove double quotes that appear within a string coming from a dB because it's causing an stream error in another application. I can't clean up the dB to remove these, so I need to replace the character on the fly.

I've tried using sed, ssed, and perl all without success. This regular expression is locating the problem quotes, but when I plug it into sed to replace them with a single quote my output still contains the double quote.

```
sed "s/(\?<\!\t|^)\"(\?\!\t|$)/'/g" test.txt
```

I'm on Mac, if this looks a bit odd.

The regex is valid, but when I test on a tab-delimited file containing this:

```
"foo"   "rea"son"   "text's"
```

My output is identical to the above. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: It seems you are trying to use lookbehind and lookahead. I don't think sed supports that. Can you show us your Perl attempt?

Comment: Is every column wrapped in quotes?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: `The regex is valid` - no, it's not because there is no such thing as "a valid regex". Every tool supports different regexp variants (e.g. BRE, ERE, PCRE) and has it's own caveats even within that (e.g. are backreferences supported, which delimiters need to be escaped, can escaped literals become ERE metachars, etc.). Online sites like rexex101, as I assume you used given your claim that "The regex is valid", are not a way to verify that any given regexp will work in any given tool and certainly not across all tools - only running it in the target tool will tell you if it's valid or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to turn all occurrences of `"` that are not on a field boundary (i.e. either preceded or succeeded by either a tab or the beginning/end of the string) by `'`.

This can be done using perl and the following substitution:

```
s/(?<=[^\t])"(?=[^\t\n])/'/g;
```

(With sed this is not directly possible as it does not support look-behind / look-ahead assertions.)

To use this code on the command line, it needs to be escaped for whatever shell you're using. Assuming bash or a similar sh-like shell:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=[^\t])"(?=[^\t\n])/'\''/g' test.txt
```

Here I use `'...'` to quote most of the code. To get a single `'` into the quoted string, I leave the quoted area `...'`, add an escaped single quote `\'`, and switch back into a single-quoted string `'...`. That's why a literal `'` turns into `'\''` on the command line.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. I had to check for newlines, because the group was capturing the last quote of a line, and the first of every line after 1.

Comment: @Jesse Oops. I believe adding `\n` to the second character class fixes that issue. Alternatively, use `perl -l` to strip newlines before matching and add them back on output.